# convert json RPC request to byte array

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, ethers.js, json-rpc, eth-call

I am new to json RPC and Ethereum.
I am trying to query 2 JSON RPC methods

**eth_sendTransaction** method

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_sendTransaction",
    "params":[
        {
        "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
        "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
        "gas": "0x76c0",
        "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000",
        "value": "0x9184e72a",
        "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
    }],
    "id":1
}
```

this is working fine, similarly their is a
**eth_sendRawTransaction** method
this method accepts bytes as an parameter

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_sendRawTransaction",
    "params":[""],
    "id":1
}
```

I am not sure how can I convert the params from eth_sendTransaction method to bytes such that it can be used in eth_sendRawTransaction?

Any help, pointer, clues are really appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with your use case and do not understand the context where you have to perform such operations. To start with ethereum development take a look on Remix IDE and hardhat. At this moment I ended up with Visual Studio Code and hardhat for my project.

Comment: I am trying to use the JSON RPC exposed by ETH clients.

Answer (score 0):

[`eth_sendRawTransaction`](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendrawtransaction) accepts a signed transaction as input parameter.

For example you could use a library like [@ethereumjs/tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) to sign a transaction.

```
import { Chain, Common, Hardfork } from '@ethereumjs/common'
import { Transaction } from '@ethereumjs/tx'

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x42',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000042',
  value: '0x00',
  data: '0x486F6C612121',
}

const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Mainnet, hardfork: Hardfork.Istanbul })
const tx = Transaction.fromTxData(txParams, { common })

const privateKey = Buffer.from(
  '20CF81D974173B77934C7EAAE54EF5B356C7DBCAEF7DCCD72C92C288FC193398',
  'hex'
)

const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey)

const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize()
```